# Помогите разобрать что выводит функция

Tags: javascript, функции

```
function bindingFunction (tobind, ...args) {
    return tobind.bind(null, ...args);
}

function tobind(...args) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<args.length; i++){
        sum += args[i];
    }
    console.log('количество аргументов =' , i);
    console.log('сумма аргументов = ' , sum);

}

var num = bindingFunction(tobind, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7);
console.log(num())
```

консоль выводит

```
количество аргументов = 6
сумма аргументов =  22
undefined
```

Помогите понять откуда взялось undefined и что это пытается вывести функция?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция num ничего не возвращает - это и есть `undefined`, который ты передаёшь в `concole.log`.

Comment: Подскажите, а как тогда правильно обратиться к функции bindingFunction ?

Comment: Просто вызывая tobind(1,2,3,4) консоль выводит, но я хочу обратиться к bindingFunction , к которой привязана tobind